# LazyVim - adding my own snippet

Tags: neovim, snippets, lazyvim

I've installed lazyvim in a linux distro and want to add my own snippets (luasnip).  Which folder do I create the file?

Comment: I assume you know where to add your own snippets in the latest version of lazyvim?

Comment: No, and I don't care because I don't use LazyVim. But, if I wanted to know where to add my own snippets to its latest version, then asking random strangers is the last thing I would do. Before that, I would read both LazyVim's and LuaSnip's documentation, try a few things, at least. You know… try to solve my self-inflicted problems myself before involving others.

Comment: Right.    I left the message here after going thru lazyvim website,  luasnip website, chatgpt, gemini, claude3, some youtube videos and others.   I needed help on getting more info, not some self-inflicted problem to fix.  All of the info presented were around 2022 before lazyvim updated their custom setup.   Now I thought I could ask any questions here to get more information regarding vim and any other software related to Vim, No?